# Odyniec imgAreaSelect plugin is not working :(

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using image area select plugin of **http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/**

I have tried making a demo on their website, but couldn't make it work :(  Please help.

**http://jsfiddle.net/PdYB7/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#bee').imgAreaSelect({ aspectRatio: '4:3', handles: true });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the css code for it to work. They have a css sheet that you can include which you can download on their site

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/imgareaselect-default.css" />
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PdYB7/5/)

```
/*
 * imgAreaSelect animated border style
 */

.imgareaselect-border1 {
    background: url(border-anim-v.gif) repeat-y left top;
}

.imgareaselect-border2 {
    background: url(border-anim-h.gif) repeat-x left top;
}

.imgareaselect-border3 {
    background: url(border-anim-v.gif) repeat-y right top;
}

.imgareaselect-border4 {
    background: url(border-anim-h.gif) repeat-x left bottom;
}

.imgareaselect-border1, .imgareaselect-border2,
.imgareaselect-border3, .imgareaselect-border4 {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

.imgareaselect-handle {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

.imgareaselect-outer {
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

.imgareaselect-selection {
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PdYB7/4/